# How to set property sort ，When i use Jpa Example.of

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How to assign property sort to generated sql? thanks

table has index , i want set index property is first in where

```
Message condition = new Message();
condition.setReceiver(account);
condition.setChannel(channel);
condition.setState(MessageState.INITIAL);

return messageRepository.findAll(Example.of(condition),Sort.by("createTime").descending());
```

The Generated  sql is :
where

```
message0_.channel=? 
and message0_.state=0 
and message0_.receiver=?
```

I want:
where

```
message0_.receiver=? 
and message0_.channel=0 
and message0_.state=?
```

Comment: For what reason, the order of `?` influencing parameter passing?

Comment: influencing index useing

Comment: won't rarely help

Answer (score 0):

There's no API available to order predicates, I'm afraid. If you want this level of control over the generated query, you're better off using a native query instead.

Why do you feel you need that, though? Most query optimizers ignore the order of predicates, in most cases. Did you actually `EXPLAIN` the version of the query generated by Spring Data to find that the index is not being used?

Comment: Well, TBH, this is a rather uncommon use case precisely because the order of predicates is irrelevant for most query optimizers. Every query optimizer worth its salt will first look for ways to use indexes, regardless of the order in which predicates happened to be defined in the query. Which database are you using? Could you post the result of `EXPLAIN` for this query?